# CSS Dropdown menu behind content

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a list of comments and provide a dropdown menu with actions for each one.

I'm running into an issue where the dropdown menu is placed behind the text of the next comment. See when you hove over a comment, you'll see the 3 menu dots appear, hover over the dots and the menu will expand behind the second comment.

I have been messing with z-index, opacity, and position for elements for a few hours now and am just running into a wall. Could use some other eyes to see what i'm missing... I know it has to be simple

```css
.post-comment {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    margin: 20px 0;
    min-height: 40px;
}

.post-comment:hover > .options > button {
    display: block;
}

.post-comment > .options {
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    min-width: 45px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.post-comment > .options > button {
    border: none !important;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0) !important;
    min-width: 45px;
    display: none;
}

.post-comment > .options > button > span {
    width: 4px;
    height: 4px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    background-color: #727272;
    margin: 2px;
}

.post-comment > .options > div {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
}

.post-comment > .options > div > a {
    padding: 10px 5px;
    border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
    color: #535353 !important;
    font-size: 14px;
    display: block;
}

.post-comment > .options > div > a:hover {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

.post-comment > .options > button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.post-comment > .options > button:hover > span {
    background-color: #505050;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.post-comment > .options > button:hover + div, .post-comment > .options > div:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-comment">
  <div>
      Author 2 hour ago<br/>
      Some juicy content. Some juicy content. Some juicy content. 
  </div>
  <div class="options">
    <button>
      <span></span><span></span><span></span>
    </button>
    <div>
      <a href="#1">Option1</a>
      <a href="#2">Option2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="post-comment">
  <div>
      Author 2 hour ago<br/>
      Some juicy content. Some juicy content. Some juicy content. Some juicy content. Some juicy content. Some juicy content. Some juicy content. Some juicy content. Some juicy content. Some juicy content. Some juicy content. Some juicy content. Some juicy content. Some juicy content. Some juicy content. 
  </div>
  <div class="options">
    <button>
      <span></span><span></span><span></span>
    </button>
    <div>
      <a href="#1">Option1</a>
      <a href="#2">Option2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to use the select statement in you want a drop down menu.  What exactly would you like to do? Can you draw a picture of what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need `z-index`, just add `background-color` to your `div`

```css
.post-comment {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    margin: 20px 0;
    min-height: 40px;
}

.post-comment:hover > .options > button {
    display: block;
}

.post-comment > .options {
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    min-width: 45px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.post-comment > .options > button {
    border: none !important;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0) !important;
    min-width: 45px;
    display: none;
}

.post-comment > .options > button > span {
    width: 4px;
    height: 4px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    background-color: #727272;
    margin: 2px;
}

.post-comment > .options > div {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
}

.post-comment > .options > div > a {
    padding: 10px 5px;
    border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
    color: #535353 !important;
    font-size: 14px;
    display: block;
}

.post-comment > .options > div > a:hover {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

.post-comment > .options > button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.post-comment > .options > button:hover > span {
    background-color: #505050;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.post-comment > .options > button:hover + div, .post-comment > .options > div:hover {
    display: block;
}
.options > div {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-comment">
  <div>
      Author 2 hour ago<br/>
      Some juicy content. Some juicy content. Some juicy content. 
  </div>
  <div class="options">
    <button>
      <span></span><span></span><span></span>
    </button>
    <div>
      <a href="#1">Option1</a>
      <a href="#2">Option2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="post-comment">
  <div>
      Author 2 hour ago<br/>
      Some juicy content. Some juicy content. Some juicy content. Some juicy content. Some juicy content. Some juicy content. Some juicy content. Some juicy content. Some juicy content. Some juicy content. Some juicy content. Some juicy content. Some juicy content. Some juicy content. Some juicy content. 
  </div>
  <div class="options">
    <button>
      <span></span><span></span><span></span>
    </button>
    <div>
      <a href="#1">Option1</a>
      <a href="#2">Option2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes its very simple. Please mark this as the correct answer.